# How do I stop iTunes from automatically opening when I browse an app on apple.com?

Tags: itunes, websites

[image]

Like when I go to one of these pages iTunes **automatically** opens up. It's really annoying. How can I disable this?

Answer (score 2):

https://gigaom.com/2010/03/15/how-to-stop-itunes-web-links-from-opening-itunes/

It looks like the browser you are using is chrome, so follow these steps

1. Go to chrome://settings/contentExceptions#javascript
2. add itunes.apple.com and mark "Block"

[image]

If you want to see the app without seeing the "Opening the iTunes Store." page, visit The [iTunes Link Maker](https://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/en-us/) and see if you can find the app on there.

(that was my solution before, but it seems now iTunes preview shows the app with a "Opening the iTunes Store." banner. By disabling Javascript on that page, you won't see the banner)

Comment: Let me know if I got the browser wrong, and I'll edit the answer. The link that I provided has the solutions for Firefox and Safari too. If they don't work, research on disabling Javascript for certain websites / iTunes

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me with the Apple Music app.

Comment: New link: chrome://settings/content/javascript

Answer (score 0):

This does not happen for me on El Capitan. When I search for an app, Evernote for example, the first Google result is the app listing on iTunes. (Screenshot below.) If I want to download the app, I have to click the blue View in iTunes button below the app icon. iTunes is never opened until View in iTunes is clicked. What version of OS X are you running? [image]

Comment: Unfortunately this happens for me on macOS Sierra.